# Guessing Game Python Infinite Loop

Tags: python, random

I am trying to teach myself basic python scripting and create the number guessing game, but I am running into an infinite loop for my while loop. The program will infinitely print the first print statement from the initial entry.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random

print("Here is a guessing game!")
print("Try to guess the number. It is a value from 1-100")

answer = random.randint(1,100)
guess = int(input('Enter your guess: '))
counter = 0

while (guess != answer):
   counter += 1
   if guess < answer:
       print('Your guess is too low!')
   elif guess > answer:
       print('Your guess is too high!')
   else:
       print('Correct!')
       print('It took you' + count + ' guesses.')
```

Comment: Either `guess` or `answer` has to be modified inside loop. Here, the `guess` input should be inside loop so it asks everytime what's your next guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Try asking the guess again in each loop until the correct answer and print the counter outside the loop

#!/usr/bin/python
import random

print("Here is a guessing game!")
print("Try to guess the number. It is a value from 1-100")

answer = random.randint(1,100)
guess = int(input('Enter your guess: '))
counter = 0

while (guess != answer):
   counter += 1
   if guess < answer:
       print('Your guess is too low!')
   elif guess > answer:
       print('Your guess is too high!')
   guess = int(input('Try again, your new guess: '))
print('Correct!')
print('It took you' + counter + ' guesses.')
```

Comment: OP does not want to have a user input every iteration of the loop

Comment: But without user input, it doesn't make a number guessing game, because if you just guessed once and the loop runs till it randomly gets that exact number you guessed, I don't see a point there.

Comment: OP is using a random number? this takes care of the user input every iteration of the loop, hence the user every iteration is invalid

Answer (score 0):

User should input a value inside the loop, so I think you need to change the code to this:

```
import random

print("Here is a guessing game!")
print("Try to guess the number. It is a value from 1-100")

answer = random.randint(1,100)
guess = int(input('Enter your guess: '))
counter = 0

while (guess != answer):
   counter += 1
   if guess < answer:
       print('Your guess is too low!')
       guess = int(input('Enter your guess: '))
   elif guess > answer:
       print('Your guess is too high!')
       guess = int(input('Enter your guess: '))
   else:
       print('Correct!')
       print('It took you' + str(counter) + ' guesses.')
```

It's because the user input the guess value once, so when it going in to loop, it will loop forever and print (too low or too high)

Comment: Similar to comment above, user input in this case is not helpful as the OP is using a random input every time.

Comment: Oh, so why the OP counting the guesses? if the user input just once, just print 'It took you 1 guesses.'. I think the random value are the answer, so we have to guess the random number and count it.